# Using DP to find number of ways to arrange any amount of knights on an NxM chessboard?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, pseudocode

How can you use dynamic programming to find the number of ways to arrange any number of knights on an N x M chessboard?

I know knights can move in an L pattern, and it can only attack other knights in the same color as it. So, in order for any two to be safe, that means that they have the same color. I can conceptually understand how I could use that to find the max number of knights you can arrange like that, but this I'm not sure about.

I know we can represent the board with length M bit strings where 1 means there is a knight and 0 else. I'm guessing we do some kind of bit mask/manipulation, but I'm having trouble figuring out the mask and base cases would be

Comment: "Any number of knights?" What does that mean? Is it the sum of (all ways to arrange 1 + all the ways to arrange 2 +...all the ways to arrange the max number possible)?

Comment: as in we dont have a number of knights we need to use. Instead, we can use any number of knights, from 0 to M*N as long as all configurations are valid (no 2 knights can attack each other) @גלעדברקן

Comment: Suppose we know the number of ways to arrange knights in rows n-1 and n-2. Then how we can use this to find all ways arrange knights in rows n and n-1?